# If statement that checks if the user entered a valid double number

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that will check if the user enters a valid double number.
I know how to make it check a valid integer by doing:

```
if (scanf("%d%c", &inter, &newLine) != 2 || newLine != '\n')
```

but when it coming to checking a double type it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
if (scanf("%d%c", &inter, &newLine) != 2.00 || newLine != '\n')
```

and:

```
if (scanf("%d%c", &inter, &newLine) != 2.000000 || newLine != '\n')
```

none of those to seem to work

here is a full example of how it checks a valid integer type;

```
do {
    num = inter % 1;

    if (scanf("%d%c", &inter, &newLine) != 2 || newLine != '\n') {

        printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");

        flushKeybord();
    } else {
        x = x + 1;
    }
} while (x == 0);
```

the function that its calling if its invalid is simply a to clear the buffer

Comment: The return value from `scanf` is not the value entered, but the number of items successfully scanned. You must use `%lf` format specifier for `double` instead of `%d`. Note too that `2.00` is identical to `2.000000`. More zeros does not mean "trying harder"!

Comment: If user enters `" 123 \n"` or `" 123\n"` or `"1.0e1000\n"`? are those valid?

Comment: yes if the user enters 123 \n that would be invalid because its not a double type same with 123\n and if the user enters 1.0e1000 that would also be invalid because the user enters a character that's not '\n'

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `scanf` thread. Don't use `scanf` for this, read the line with `fgets` and then parse it with `sscanf` or `strtok`, etc. See [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Besides, `scanf` returns the number of input items **successfully** matched and assigned.

// edit: use `strtod` for things like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];
    double d;
    char *pEnd;

    for(;;)
    {
        // here you should check if fgets returns NULL
        fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

        int len = strlen(line);

        if(line[len-1] == '\n')
            line[len-1] = 0;

        d = strtod(line, &pEnd);    

        if(*pEnd == 0 && len > 0)
        {
            printf("Double: %lf\n", d);
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Wrong format, try again\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's right. I usually remove `\n` and trailing white spaces and then run the input through `strtod` and then check `*pEnd == 0`. I didn't do that to keep the code simple. I'll fix it

Comment: Detail: `if(line[len-1] == '\n')` is better as `if(len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n')` or use `line[strcspn(line,"\n")]=0;` to cope with `fgets()` _reading_ an initial null character.